# Problem with Java function using tree recursion

Tags: java, function, recursion, tree, racket

I'm having a problem in translating code from Racket to Java.

I wrote a procedure, in Racket, that resolves a 3D version of the "Streets of Manhattan" problem.

The problem is that, in Racket, the creation of a tree type recursion to resolve the problem, is extremely easy, while, in Java, I'm having some problems. 
I learned that I should use Nodes for tree recursion in Java, but I have no idea of how they work.
Any hints?

Here is the original Racket code that I need to translate in Java:

```
(define (manhattan-3d i j k)
    (cond
      [(and (= i 0) (= j 0)) 1]
      [(and (= i 0) (= k 0)) 1]
      [(and (= j 0) (= k 0)) 1]
      [(or (= i -1) (= j -1) (= k -1)) 0]
      [(or (and (> i 0) (> j 0)) (and (> i 0) (> k 0)) (and (> j 0) (> k 0))) (+ (manhattan-3d (- i 1) j k) (manhattan-3d i (- j 1) k) (manhattan-3d i j (- k 1)))]
     )
  )
```

As you can see, in Racket it's a pretty easy and short procedure, but I have no idea of how to resolve it in Java.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried translating it directly, using just `int`s? Because I don't see anything in that piece of code which can't be *directly* translated to Java. The major risk using recursion in Java is that it doesn't perform tail-call elimination, but neither would racket, in this case it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any tree in this code.

While I don't know racket, the code seems understandable enough.

It looks like all you need are several conditions:

```
public static int manhattan3d (int i, int j, int k) 
{
    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (i == 0 && k == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (j == 0 && k == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (i == -1 || j == -1 || k == -1)
        return 0;
    else
        return manhattan3d (i - 1, j, k) + manhattan3d (i, j - 1, k) + manhattan3d (i, j k - 1);
}
```

Comment: I came to a similar solution...but yours actually works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use Nodes in java to create a tree.

A Node class in java is a class who contains at least a name and a list of nodes called childrens.

[image]

Here the node 1 has 2 and 3 as its childrens.

The node 2 has 4 and 5 as its children, ...

Each node of a tree is an instance of the class node. To go to a node you have to use a recursive method.

Comment: "You shoul use Nodes in java." why?

Comment: Not here sorry, I edited to fix that but i though that the asker want to know how to create a tree.